# select union does not summarize selection

Tags: php, mysql

If I select `1` post from table `posts`
plus (union) `11` posts form table `parchive`
the final count is not 12 but 11:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where status='public' order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset);
    $count1 = $stmt->rowCount(); // echo: 1
    if ($count1 < 12){
        $diff = 12 - $count1;
        $stmt = $db->query("(select * from posts where status='public' order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset . ")
        union (select * from parchive where status='public' order by date desc limit " . $diff .")");
        $count2 = $stmt->rowCount(); // echo 11
    }
```

So if `$count1` is `1` and `$diff` is `11`
`$count2` should be `12 (1+11)` and not `11` !

Comment: You have only 10 matching posts in `parchive`

Comment: remember that union remove duplicated  values

Comment: @scaisEdge, you're right, duplicated values was the problem. Is there a way to keep them selected, although duplicated ?

Comment: @bonaca  . i have posted  an aswer hope is useful

Comment: @scaisEdge, yes , I see and it is accepted already. You're a coding wizard, believe me.

Comment: @bonaca  . thanks  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  all the result and not remove duplicated  values use union ALL

```
$stmt = $db->query("(select * 
        from posts where status='public' order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset . ")
 union all  (select * 
  from parchive where status='public' order by date desc limit " . $diff .")");
```